# How to print all lines until newline after given word matched

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I want to print all the lines until newline after given word matched

**File:**

```
[`odbcname`]  
Driver       = /`usr`/lib/`odbc`/`libmyodbc.so`  
Description  = `MyODBC`3.51 Driver `DSN`  
SERVER       = my.database.server.com  
PORT         =  

[`MSSQLTestServer`]   
Driver       = `FreeTDS`
```

**Output:**

```
[`odbcname`]  
Driver       = /`usr`/lib/`odbc`/`libmyodbc.so`  
Description  = `MyODBC` 3.51 Driver `DSN`  
SERVER       = my.database.server.com  
PORT         =
```

I tried

```
cat grep '^\[odbcname]|^$'`
```

but i don't know how to print all  lines until empty space.

Comment: see [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), avoid quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -v RS= '/\[odbcname\]/' file

[odbcname]
Driver = /usr/lib/odbc/libmyodbc.so
Description = MyODBC3.51 Driver DSN
SERVER = my.database.server.com
PORT =
```

set record separator to paragraph mode (i.e. one or more blank lines), find the the pattern (and print).

Comment: Could u please explain me that hoe the characters /\[ is working

Comment: `[...]` defines a char range, i.e. `[0-9]`, if you don't escape the brackets any combination of the chars "odbcname" would match the header.  Try for example with `/[cbdo]/`

Comment: here of course you could have used equality as well `$0=="[obdcname]"`

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` you can do something like this:

```
$ awk '/odbcname/,NF==0' file
[odbcname]
Driver = /usr/lib/odbc/libmyodbc.so
Description = MyODBC3.51 Driver DSN
SERVER = my.database.server.com
PORT =
```

Another somewhat more versatile way to do the same is:

```
awk '/odbcname/{p=1}p;NF==0{p=0}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
$ sed -n '/^\[odbcname\]/,/^$/{/^$/d;p}' file
[odbcname]
Driver = /usr/lib/odbc/libmyodbc.so
Description = MyODBC3.51 Driver DSN
SERVER = my.database.server.com
PORT =
```